# How to find out name of package I want to remove with Yum in Amazon Fedora EC2 instance

Tags: fedora, yum

So I installed Python 3.7 on my EC2 Fedora instance with Yum, later I needed to remove it. However, when I did yum -list, it showed all the "sub-packages" installed with python.

I just typed yum remove python3 and it worked, but what is the "proper" way of figuring out what name you need to type to remove a package cleaningly?

Comment: there is nothing else to do. The package is removed... what is the problem?

Comment: It feels like I'm just guessing what name I should be typing to remove Python 3.7 and all related packages. I want to know how to do it properly for future package removals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but I'll try to answer.

### 1. You installed python3.7 your self

when you installed python3.7, you typed

```
yum install python3
```

so if you want to remove it, you can type the same name that you use to install it:

```
yum remove python3
```

### 2. someone else installed it

In this case you can trace the binary that you want to remove, let's say `python3.7`. First you can see what is the full path of that binary:

```
which python3.7
```

which gives

```
/usr/bin/python3.7
```

now you can query which package installed that file:

```
rpm -qf /usr/bin/python3.7
```

which will yield the full package name, something like:

```
python36-3.6.8-2.module_el8.0.0+33+0a10c0e1.x86_64
```

which you can then use to remove it:

```
yum remove python36-3.6.8-2.module_el8.0.0+33+0a10c0e1.x86_64
```